# MySQL display results that were not joined

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am joining two tables with the following query:

```
select * from t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.First1=t2.FirstName 
and t1.Last1=t2.LastName 
and t1.City=t2.City
and t1.ST=t2.State;
```

Now, how do I run a separate query to print out the rows from t2 that were not joined?

I tried using NOT IN for a field but I receive the error: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
select * from t2 where t2.RefID NOT IN (
select * from t1,t2 where t1.First1=t2.FirstName 
and t1.Last1=t2.LastName 
and t1.City=t2.City
and t1.ST=t2.State);
```

Comment: "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" Yes logical `t2.RefID NOT IN(select * ...)` You can't use * when using NOT IN with one column value... But MySQL allowes you to use this SQL `WHERE (column1, column) IN (SELECT column1, columns ...)`

Comment: If you want to display the non joined or non matching values from t2 only you can simply add a `WHERE  t2.anny_column IS NULL` statement to the LEFT JOIN query

Comment: Your NOT IN fails because it must be of the format `X IN (SELECT single_field...` or `(X, Y, ...) IN (SELECT X, Y, ....` It probably would have worked fine if the subquery was `SELECT t2.RefID...`; but see my answer for a query that may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t1
                  WHERE t1.First1=t2.FirstName 
                    AND t1.Last1=t2.LastName 
                    AND t1.City=t2.City
                    AND t1.ST=t2.State);
```

Before using `NOT IN` you sould keep in mind that:

> The most important thing to note about NOT EXISTS and NOT IN is that, unlike EXISTS and IN,  they are not equivalent in all cases. Specifically, when NULLs are involved they will return different results. To be totally specific, when the subquery returns even one null, NOT IN will not match any rows.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the join and check for unmatched...

```
select * from t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.First1=t2.FirstName 
and t1.Last1=t2.LastName 
and t1.City=t2.City
and t1.ST=t2.State
WHERE t1.someid IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me that I also could have just flipped the join!